# A particular embedding of a Lie group in Euclidean space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I apologize in advance if my question is elementary.
Before I present my question I mention my motivation:

## Motivation:

A Lie group is a  manifold. At the same time it is  a Riemannian manifold equipped with an invariant  metric. Moreover its tangent space at the neutral element is  a  Lie  algebra.

On the other hand every manifold can be embedded in some  Euclidean space. Furthermore this embedding can be chosen to be an isometric embedding. Moreover every lie algebra can be   embedded in an inner  Lie algebra, an algebra  with an inner Lie bracket $[a,b]=ab-ba$.

In our question, for  a  given Lie group,  we would like to  combine all (or parts of) these properties.

## Question:

Let $G$ be  a  Lie group  with neutral element $e$. Is there an algebra structure on some $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a smooth embedding $f:G \to \mathbb{R}^n$ with $f(e)=0$ such that $Df_e$ carries $T_e G$  to a sub  Lie  algebra of  $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the inner Lie  structure $[a,b]=ab-ba$?Can we  choose such $f:G \to \mathbb{R}^n$  an isometric embedding  where $G$ is equipped  with an invariant metric  and $\mathbb{R}^n$ with its  standard metric? Can we choose such an $f$ such that $Df_g$  carry all tangent spaces $T_g G,\;g\in G  $ to a Lie Subalgebra of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a Lie algebra embedding?

## A trivial example:

The embedding of circle in the plane, when we equipe the plane  with an arbitrary  commutative algebra structure, satisfies all requirements of the question.

Comment: Every (real) Lie group is a finite cover of a linear Lie group (*i.e.*, a closed subgroup of some $\mathrm{GL}_m(\mathbb R)$), and this can obviously be done for linear Lie groups; so maybe it's enough to show that this condition is preserved under covers?  (Or, if it's false, then a non-linear group like a spin or metaplectic group is the place to look.)

Comment: @LSpice  It is interesting to think about non linear  ones. BTW I was not aware of  the fact that every Lie group is  a cover of  a  linear group. Thanks  for  this point and for your comment.

Comment: @LSpice  However it is not an isometric embedding/

Comment: @LSpice no (1) the universal covering of $SL_2(R)$ is not finite cover of a linear Lie group (2) the quotient of the Heisenberg group by an infinite cyclic central subgroup has no cover at all that is a linear Lie group. Also there are two definitions of linear: has an injective continuous representations, vs has one with closed image. These are equivalent, but it's a theorem (maybe of Mostow, I don't remember right now).

Comment: @AliTaghavi unfortunately there are two non-equivalent definitions of isometric embedding: isometric for the distance, or infinitesimally isometric (i.e. the pull-back of the Riemannian metric of the target space equals the Riemannian metric of the left-hand space). Which one do you have in mind (one can even imagine intermediate notions, such as "locally isometric", i.e. preserving small distances).

Comment: @YCor  I mean the second one, according to Nash embedding theorem,

Comment: @AliTaghavi by algebra do you mean associative algebra? (there are interesting structures, called pre-Lie algebras or left-symmetric algebras, whose brackets are Lie brackets). Also, I guess that by "invariant metric" you mean "left-invariant metric"?

Comment: @YCor, indeed, I appear to have been quoting a theorem without remembering it.  There's *some* statement describing the farthest a Lie group can be from being linear, though, right?  (Also, I think your wording in [(2)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293236/a-particular-embedding-of-a-lie-group-in-euclidean-space) must be backwards, right?  I did not claim that an arbitrary Lie group is *covered by* a linear Lie group, but rather that it *covers* one.)

Comment: @LSpice yes in (2) I meant "does not cover at all any". In general I don't think we can say better than having a common cover with a linear Lie group: the direct product of the $\widetilde{SL_2}$ example and the Heisenberg/cyclic examples has no cover and does not cover a linear Lie group.

Comment: @YCor  Yes I mean associative algebra, since I was motivated by the fact that  every Lie  algebra can be embedded in an inner Lie  algebra, an associative algebra with inner Lie  bracket. As for  invariant metric, I mean left  invariant.

Comment: @Ycor  I always thought two concepts of isometry are equivalent in the following sense: Assume $f:M \to  N$ is a diffeomorphism. Then  f preserve the distance iff   $Df$ preserve the inner product.But  I think that you said it is not the case.Am Yes? What is a counter example?

Comment: @AliTaghavi just any embedding of $\mathbf{R}$ into $\mathbf{R}^d$. It's isometric for the distance iff it is an affine map. Same for locally isometric (in the sense of small distance). But it's infinitesimally isometric as soon as its derivative has norm 1 everywhere, which holds much more often. (If we post-compose an affine map $\mathbf{R}$ into $\mathbf{R}^d$ with the quotient map from $\mathbf{R}^d$ to a torus, we obtain a locally isometric map that is not distance-isometric.)

Comment: @Ycor an affine map is distance preserving?  By affine do you mean $tA+B$? Are you sure it preserve the distance?

Comment: @AliTaghavi Yes by affine I mean $t\mapsto tu+v$, for $u,v\in\mathbf{R}^d$. Of course yes, I need $\|u\|=1$ for it to be an isometry.

Comment: @Ycor I think I am missingsome thing. You wrot e in your 2 previous comment  that e an arbitrary  affine map is isometric in distance. Is it correct?

Comment: @AliTaghavi I said in my previous comment that I forgot to assume that the speed is 1. An affine map $t\mapsto tu+v$ is isometric (in any possible sense) if and only if $\|u\|=1$.

Comment: @Ycor  So I  think two notion s of "isometry" are equivalent. Right?  That is distance preserving  isometries and   infinitiesimally  isometries are the same.

Answer (score 1):

For a linear group, it would seem that the defining embedding $G\hookrightarrow GL(n, \mathbb{R}) \to M^{n\times n}$ works, no?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. yes  but it is  not an isometric embedding.

Comment: Is there an isometric embedding of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ into some $M^{k\times k}$  whose derivative preserves the Lie algebra structure?

Comment: @AliTaghavi, $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb R) \to \mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb R)$ does it; its derivative is the identity map.

Comment: @LSpice  but it is not an isometry since the metric of  $GL(n,R)$ is not  the Euclidean metric.

Comment: @AliTaghavi, sorry; I missed the word 'isometric'.